# An alternative rule of inference in typed lambda calculus

Tags: type-theory

The typical rules of inference in typed lambda calculus are:
$$\frac{X : U, Y : U}{X \rightarrow Y :U}$$

$$\frac{a : X \rightarrow Y, b : X}{ab : Y}$$

$$\frac{x : X \vdash a : Y}{\lambda x . a}$$

$$(\lambda x . a )(b) \equiv a [ x \backslash b] $$

I was wondering if we could instead take the rule:

$$\frac{a : X \rightarrow Y}{b : Y \vdash ab : Y}$$
(instead of the second one). If not, can someone explain why?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine yes, you were right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the presence of weakening and substitution, parameterised rules are admissible. This is a general result, and holds in the special case of the simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus. It is stated explicitly, for instance, as Proposition 6.4 of Arkor–Fiore's [Algebraic models of simple type theories: a polynomial approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16949).

Here is a simple proof. I've used a slightly different notation to your question to be clearer and consistent with the standard notation.

We will show that the following two operators, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are interderivable.

[image: A_1 and A_2]

1. $A_1$ is derivable from $A_2$.

[image: A_2 implies A_1]

2. $A_2$ is derivable from $A_1$.

[image: A_1 implies A_2]

Preservation of the the equations is left as an exercise for the reader :)